# Oracle 11g Express VMWare settings

Tags: oracle, vmware

I have a VMWare workstation installation that I am attempting to add a CentOS vm to the library.  VM starts up fine in either NAT or Bridge mode.
  However, when starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition, oracle fails to start properly in the VM when it is in NAT mode.  It *does* start properly when in bridged mode.  Clues as to what I've got set wrong?

Some status outputs when in NAT mode:

```
# rdbsh
// Oracle connection request failed, retrying...
// WARN dbm_oci_connect.c 116: Oracle connection request using yada/yada@XE failed with code: 1034

# sqlplus user/password@XE
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I don't know VMVare, I am using Oracle VirtualBox, in my configuration I have two adapters - one NAT (it gives me internet connection on VM), and another one in bridge mode using static IP. Oracle database works (listen to) on second adapter. Also disable firewall on your worstation if you are using Windows (at least add a rule to enable traffic on port 1521, because the firewal blocks almost all ports by default).

Comment: Please show us the oracle environment : set | grep ORA. cat /etc/oratab, # login as sys: "sqlplus / as sysdba" SQL>startup